# Debugging hs_err_pid.log files

Tags: hs-err

I've not encountered many of these and have no idea on how to debug these, any help is appreciated. When I run the program and this log occurs the whole program closes.

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03a6bc00):  JavaThread "Thread-4" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=4532, stack(0x03b20000,0x03b70000)]
siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x03a6bc00, ECX=0x03a6bc00, EDX=0x6dad70a0
ESP=0x03b6e238, EBP=0x03b6e254, ESI=0x03a6bd10, EDI=0x3b472ff8
EIP=0x6d9a5105, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x03b6e238)
0x03b6e238:   3b472ff8 03a6bd10 3059b9b8 03a6bc00
0x03b6e248:   03c7baa4 0000007f 6dad70a0 03b6e274
0x03b6e258:   30591ee9 03a6bd10 00000000 04d64690
0x03b6e268:   03b6f0ac 3b472ff8 3059b9b8 03b6f0b8
0x03b6e278:   3059b9c8 03a6bd10 30690427 03b6f0ac
0x03b6e288:   03b6e50c 03b6e29c 03b6f0ac 3059b9b8
0x03b6e298:   03b6f0b8 03b6e2c8 30687629 3059b9b8
0x03b6e2a8:   03b6f0ac 00000100 03b6e320 30687315 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d9a5105)
0x6d9a50f5:   00 00 00 74 08 8d 4d f0 e8 be 98 08 00 8b 45 0c
0x6d9a5105:   8b 00 50 e8 d3 90 ff ff 8b f0 8b 7e 44 83 c6 08 


Stack: [0x03b20000,0x03b70000],  sp=0x03b6e238,  free space=312k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xf5105]
C  [sw3d.dll+0x1ee9]
C  [sw3d.dll+0xb9c8]
J  fa.o(JIIJII)V
J  fa.a(IILta;II)V
J  peb.a(Lta;BILama;IIILpeb;)V
J  lia.a(Lpeb;IILta;IIIILra;)V
j  lba.a(IIIIZIII[Lpeb;II)V+3511
j  lba.a(IIIIZIII[Lpeb;II)V+8013
J  ava.a(IIIIIIBII)V
J  oea.a(B)V
J  iva.a(JI)V
J  client.n(I)V
J  client.a(B)V
J  oe.j(I)V
J  oe.i(I)V
j  oe.run()V+11
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xecf9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1741d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xed167]
V  [jvm.dll+0xed1dd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x116290]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d0414]
V  [jvm.dll+0x173e4c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  fa.o(JIIJII)V
J  fa.a(IILta;II)V
J  peb.a(Lta;BILama;IIILpeb;)V
J  lia.a(Lpeb;IILta;IIIILra;)V
j  lba.a(IIIIZIII[Lpeb;II)V+3511
j  lba.a(IIIIZIII[Lpeb;II)V+8013
J  ava.a(IIIIIIBII)V
J  oea.a(B)V
J  iva.a(JI)V
J  client.n(I)V
J  client.a(B)V
J  oe.j(I)V
J  oe.i(I)V
j  oe.run()V+11
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
0x2ebab400 JavaThread "Thread-40" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4388, stack(0x06840000,0x06890000)]
0x2e5b7800 JavaThread "Thread-39" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5788, stack(0x067a0000,0x067f0000)]
0x03ad4400 JavaThread "Thread-17" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5764, stack(0x04b70000,0x04bc0000)]
0x03377400 JavaThread "Thread-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1236, stack(0x05330000,0x05380000)]
0x0333c000 JavaThread "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5792, stack(0x05140000,0x05190000)]
0x03ab0800 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3488, stack(0x04d00000,0x04d50000)]
0x03d03800 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5512, stack(0x04cb0000,0x04d00000)]
0x03bdd800 JavaThread "Thread-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2944, stack(0x04c60000,0x04cb0000)]
0x0337e400 JavaThread "Thread-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3220, stack(0x04c10000,0x04c60000)]
0x03e13400 JavaThread "Thread-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1808, stack(0x04bc0000,0x04c10000)]
0x02c94800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=888, stack(0x044d0000,0x04520000)]
0x03c83400 JavaThread "Trident pulse source thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5344, stack(0x04400000,0x04450000)]
0x0337d400 JavaThread "Trident callback thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4232, stack(0x043b0000,0x04400000)]
=>0x03a6bc00 JavaThread "Thread-4" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=4532, stack(0x03b20000,0x03b70000)]
0x0323c000 JavaThread "Substance heap status" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5472, stack(0x03660000,0x036b0000)]
0x003a6800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=5672, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]
0x02ce7000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=6100, stack(0x03130000,0x03180000)]
0x02ce5800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4248, stack(0x030a0000,0x030f0000)]
0x02ce4000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5900, stack(0x03050000,0x030a0000)]
0x02ce3400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2164, stack(0x03000000,0x03050000)]
0x02c55c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4944, stack(0x02ed0000,0x02f20000)]
0x02c52c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5596, stack(0x02e80000,0x02ed0000)]
0x02c51400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5592, stack(0x02e30000,0x02e80000)]
0x02c50000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5576, stack(0x02de0000,0x02e30000)]
0x02c0e000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5700, stack(0x02d90000,0x02de0000)]
0x02c0cc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2908, stack(0x02d40000,0x02d90000)]

Other Threads:
0x02c0b000 VMThread [stack: 0x02cf0000,0x02d40000] [id=4908]
0x02c69800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02f20000,0x02f70000] [id=5608]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
def new generation   total 6464K, used 5539K [0x06990000, 0x07090000, 0x090f0000)
eden space 5760K,  83% used [0x06990000, 0x06e48da0, 0x06f30000)
from space 704K, 100% used [0x06f30000, 0x06fe0000, 0x06fe0000)
to   space 704K,   0% used [0x06fe0000, 0x06fe0000, 0x07090000)
tenured generation   total 85168K, used 64224K [0x090f0000, 0x0e41c000, 0x26990000)
the space 85168K,  75% used [0x090f0000, 0x0cfa8258, 0x0cfa8400, 0x0e41c000)
compacting perm gen  total 14080K, used 13960K [0x26990000, 0x27750000, 0x2a990000)
the space 14080K,  99% used [0x26990000, 0x27732250, 0x27732400, 0x27750000)
ro space 8192K,  67% used [0x2a990000, 0x2aef8230, 0x2aef8400, 0x2b190000)
rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x2b190000, 0x2b80d678, 0x2b80d800, 0x2bd90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db3b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d1fa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x774e0000 - 0x7761e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\comctl32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d2e0000 - 0x6d334000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d6c0000 - 0x6d6d3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x58d40000 - 0x58d47000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wship6.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d6e9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x4fdd0000 - 0x4ff76000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x03640000 - 0x03646000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d250000 - 0x6d273000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\dcpr.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x6d620000 - 0x6d6b3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\mlib_image.dll
0x6d500000 - 0x6d524000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x6d5d0000 - 0x6d5f4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\jsound.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d608000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\jsoundds.dll
0x73f10000 - 0x73f6c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DSOUND.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76c5e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x77a80000 - 0x77b15000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76cb8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
0x72d20000 - 0x72d29000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wdmaud.drv
0x72d10000 - 0x72d18000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msacm32.drv
0x77be0000 - 0x77bf5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSACM32.dll
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bd7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\midimap.dll
0x73ee0000 - 0x73ee4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KsUser.dll
0x036b0000 - 0x036da000     C:\Documents and Settings\admin\jagexcache\runescape\LIVE\jaclib.dll
0x6d410000 - 0x6d416000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\jawt.dll
0x76fd0000 - 0x7704f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77050000 - 0x77115000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x74ef0000 - 0x74ef8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
0x75290000 - 0x752c7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemcomn.dll
0x06480000 - 0x06745000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x74ed0000 - 0x74ede000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
0x75690000 - 0x75706000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
0x76080000 - 0x760e5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCP60.dll
0x767a0000 - 0x767b3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NTDSAPI.dll
0x30590000 - 0x3072d000     C:\Documents and Settings\admin\jagexcache\runescape\LIVE\sw3d.dll
0x59a60000 - 0x59b01000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: org.program.MainProgram
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\eclipse;
USERNAME=admin
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 15 model 6 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2095528k(681948k free), swap 3510444k(2093216k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.3-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_17-b04), built on Oct 11 2009 00:52:06 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Tue Mar 13 18:01:18 2012
elapsed time: 719 seconds
```

I wish to know what causes it and how to correct it please.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug (null pointer passed to a jnienv function) in sw3d.dll.

It's a part of the game RuneScape. To avoid running sw3d.dll, you must not use the "software" display mode in RuneScape. Switch to the DirectX or OpenGL mode.